# Icon not changing when using pyinstaller in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pyinstaller, raspberry-pi4

I executed the following commands to convert my python to an executable file:

1. pyinstaller Calculator3.py --onefile --icon="cuisine.ico"
2. pyinstaller -w -F -i "cuisine.ico" Calculator3.py
3. pyinstaller --onefile --icon="cuisine.ico" --clean Calculator3.py

The icon does not change to cuisine.ico, but it remains as the pyinstaller's default icon.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

icon="cuisine.ico" only use on windows os
so  raspberry you can user .desktop file on desktop